# Equivalence between two integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to prove the equality of the two integrals

$$ I_1 = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1+x)(1+2x)} dx$$
and
$$ I_2 = -\int_0^1 \frac{(-x+2)^2-1 -\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-{(-x+1)}^2}}{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-{(-x+1)}^2}\right )(1-x)(3-2x)} dx.$$

Mathematica can solve this and the solution is for both integral

$$I_{1/2} = \frac{1}{4} [-\pi - 2 \sqrt{3} \log(2 - \sqrt{3})].$$

What I would like is a simple proof of the equality $I_1 = I_2$, without having to calculate the solution directly.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: We can multiple the integrand of $I_2$ by $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-{(-x+1)}^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-{(-x+1)}^2}}$. After a substitution $u = 1-x$ we get

$$I_2 = \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1+x)(1+2x)} \frac{(2x-5)(1+x)}{(1-2x)(1-x)}.$$ Almost there but I still can't conclude.

Comment: Doesn't look right to me. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/equpjcmq58

Comment: @K.defaoite Your second integral is false. Look at the parenthesis in the denominator of g(x). https://www.desmos.com/calculator/w3zkhxl11o

Comment: My mistake, sorry.

Comment: Have you tried substitutions like $u=1-x$ or $u=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$? Sometimes that works, and I also see that $1+2(1-x)=3-2x$, so maybe there is something there. Plus, sometimes integrals like $I_1-I_2$ just happen to be equal to zero.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein Indeed I tried these substitutions but it didn't help me to prove equality. I'll continue searching.

Comment: Per your edit, you should have ended up with[$$I_2=\int_0^1\frac{(1+2x)\sqrt{2x-x^2}- 4x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x(1-2x)(1+2x)}\,dx$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+%28%281%2B2x%29+sqrt%282x-x%5E2%29+-+4x+sqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29%2F%28x*%281-4x%5E2%29%29+from+0+to+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recognize that the differential of the two integrands is

\begin{align}
& \frac{1 +\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-{(1-x)}^2}- (2-x)^2}{\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-{(1-x)}^2}\right )(1-x)(3-2x)}\\
&-\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1+x)(1+2x)}
=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
 - \frac1{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}\\
&\>\>\>\>-3\bigg(\frac1{(1-4x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}} +  
\frac1{[1-4(1-x)^2]\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2} }\bigg)
\end{align}
which leads to
$$I_2-I_1 = K_1 -3K_2$$
where $K_1$ and $K_2$ vanish as seen below
\begin{align}
K_1 &=\int_0^1 \frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
 - \frac1{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}}\overset{x\to 1-x}{dx}=-K_1=0\\
K_2 &=\int_0^1 \frac1{(1-4x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}} +  
\frac1{[1-4(1-x)^2]\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2} }\ dx \\
&= \frac2{\sqrt3}\bigg(\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt3x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} - \tanh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{1-(1-x)^2}} {\sqrt3(1-x)}\bigg)\bigg|_0^{\frac12}=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This is not what you asked for, but it won't fit into a comment, so I am putting it into an answer. At least for integral $I_1$, it may take less effort to calculate its value directly than to transform it into $I_2$. For example, we have that
$$
I_1=\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1+x)(1+2x)} \, dx = \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+2x}\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1+x}} \, dx.
$$
Let's try the substitution $u=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$. Then $x=\dfrac{1-u}{1+u}$ and $dx=-\dfrac{2}{(1+u)^2}\,du$, so
$$
\begin{split}
I_1&=\int_1^0 \frac{1}{1+2\frac{1-u}{1+u}}\sqrt{u}\left(-\frac{2}{(1+u)^2}\right)du = \int_0^1\frac{2\sqrt{u}}{(1+u)(3-u)}\,du\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{4v^2}{(1+v^2)(3-v^2)}\,dv = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{3}{3-v^2}-\frac{1}{1+v^2}\right)dv\\
&=\left.\left(\sqrt{3}\operatorname{arctanh}\frac{v}{\sqrt{3}}-\arctan v\right)\right|_0^1
=\left.\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+v}{\sqrt{3}-v}\right)-\arctan v\right)\right|_0^1\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\ln(2+\sqrt{3})-\frac{\pi}{4}.
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us multiple the integrand of $I_2$ by $\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-{(-x+1)}^2}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}-\sqrt{1-{(-x+1)}^2}}$. We get

$$ I_2 = - \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1-2x)(1-x)} - 4\frac{\sqrt{1-(-x+1)^2}}{(1-2x)(3-2x)}. $$

Each terms of $I_2$ is divergent but $I_2$ is convergent. Let us add and subtract $4\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1-2x)(1+2x)}$ to the integrand. We obtain two convergent integrals $I_2 = I'_2 + I''_2$ with

$$I'_2 = - \int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1-2x)(1-x)} - 4\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1-2x)(1+2x)}$$ and

$$I''_2 = - \int_0^1 4\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{(1-2x)(1+2x)} - 4\frac{\sqrt{1-(-x+1)^2}}{(1-2x)(3-2x)}. $$

Following the method of @AlexanderBurstein we can prove easily that

$I_2' = I_1 + \pi$. We can show that $I''_2=-\pi$ such that
$$I_1 = I_2.$$

Edit: Let us prove that $I''_2=-\pi$. It is easy to show that

$$I''_2 = 4 P.V. \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{4x^2-1}.$$

To solve this we can use complex integration with a [dogbone contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#Example_6_%E2%80%93_logarithms_and_the_residue_at_infinity). The integral will be equal to the residue at $z=\infty$. We get

$$2I''_2 = -2\pi i\  \text{Res}[4\frac{\sqrt{1-z^2}}{4z^2-1}; z=\infty]$$
$$ 2I''_2 = -2\pi i \times -i $$
$$ I''_2 = \pi.$$